# Bash, Awk and Oracle

Tags: oracle, bash, awk

I have a problem with one of my script. I have a list of information, each line contains 3 words (or chains of word) separated by a ;
What I have to do is read this file and save the information into an Oracle Database. The first column is an user ID, the second is the first name and the third is the last name. In order to keep the spaces (for the complex names for example) I wanted to use awk. But it doesn't work... What I wrote is :

```
cat List_employees_a.csv | awk -F ";" '{
sqlplus -s << EOF
${UR_ID}/${PASSWD}@AIM
insert into UAM.USER_DEFINITION values (UPPER('${1}'),LOWER('${2}'),UPPER('${3}'));
COMMIT;
exit;
EOF}'
```

I tried to put ; at the end of each line to properly separate the instructions but it did not change anything...

Comment: 'It doesn't work' is not helpful. What happens - do you get an error, or the inserted data isn't what you expect? Showing sample data and what gets inserted (if anything) would help too.

Comment: You can't execute arbitrary commands in `awk` it's not a shell it's a programming language.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use awk? You could accomplish this task much more easily and efficiently with Oracle external tables.

Comment: @oz380 - absolutely everything is wrong with your script. You need to find someone who understands shell basics to write it for you and explain it to you.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use `bash read` instead of `awk` and create an sql file which you can later source in `sqlplus`.

For example, the following will create an sql file:

```
while IFS=';' read -r id fname lname; do 
    echo "insert into UAM.USER_DEFINITION values (UPPER('${id}'),LOWER('${fname}'),UPPER('${lname}'));"
done < List_employees_a.csv > sql.file
```

For the following file:

```
$ cat c.csv 
ida;abc acff;foeee
idc;fiffh fhfhf fhhhg;aaa
```

If you run the above command it will create an sql file like follows:

```
$ cat sql.file 
insert into UAM.USER_DEFINITION values (UPPER('ida'),LOWER('abc acff'),UPPER('foeee'));
insert into UAM.USER_DEFINITION values (UPPER('idc'),LOWER('fiffh fhfhf fhhhg'),UPPER('aaa'));
```

Once your sqlfile is created, login to sqlplus and do:

```
SQL > @/path/to/script/file/sql.file
```

This would prevent you from opening an sql connection everytime your read a line.